# How to adjust the context constraint to access my monad transformer features within a list?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

In the following function, I can access my monad transformer features

`resolverExpression :: GraphQL o => Model.Mix -> Object o GqlType.Expression`

... using the following within a do block

`lift . logDebugN $ ("log stuff here")`

However, inside a list, I do not know how to access my logging capacity. For instance, in the following function

`noAccessToFeatures :: GraphQL o => Model.Mix -> [Object o GqlType.Expression]`

#### Tentative solution

Use a `let` clause to call a subroutine that produces a single value (`:: Object o GqlType.Expression`).  Use the `in` clause to produce the final return value.

```hs
let value = go input
 in [value]

where 
  go input = do
     lift . logDebugN ("log stuff here")
     mkValue input
```

Is there not another way inside a do block? Thank you to anyone that may have a solution to this problem.

- E

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: I appreciate your request.  However, I don't think I have what it takes to generate a minimal case without a bunch of work.  The situation in a nutshell: in using a function that produces a list instead of individual values, I have lost my ability to access the monad transformer.  The individual values have access, not a list of values.  For instance, I can't seem to create a subroutine that say returns an individual value that I ultimately ignore.

Comment: Maybe your result type should be `Object o [Expression]`? The whole question is really strangely worded. Maybe you can explain more about the context in which this function would fit, because there could be some misconception hiding there.